# Show that $f(x)=g(x^{p^e})$ and each root has the same multiplicity

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, field-theory

Let $K$ a field of characteristic $p\neq 0$ and let $f(x) \in K[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial.

1. Show that $f(x)=g(x^{p^e}), e \geq 0$, where $g(x)$ is an irreducible separable polynomial of $K[x]$.
2. Show that each root of $f(x)$ in an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$ has the same multiplicity $p^e$.

Could you give me some hints how to show the two sentences??

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you are looking for hints instead of a full solution, so here is a possible plan:

1) 
Lemma: If $f\in K[x]$ is a polynomial, then $f$ has has no repeated roots in $\overline{K}$ if and only if $f$ and $f'$ has no common factor. Here, $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ (e.g. if $f(x)= x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, then $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1$).

The product rule might be useful. Once you convince yourself of the lemma, then

Corollary: If $f$ is irreducible in the lemma above, then $f$ is separable if and only if $f'\neq 0$.

Now, use the corollary above to show that $f$ is not separable if and only if $f$ is a polynomial in $x^p$, i.e. $f(x)=f_1(x^p)$ for some $f_1$. Repeat the process on $f_1$.

2) Once you have 1), using the fact that $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ in characteristic $p$, show that there exists $h\in \overline{K}[x]$ such that $h(x)^{p^e}=g(x^{p^e})=f(x)$.

Comment: 1) Could you explain further to me why we have to show that $f$ is not separable if and only if $f$ is a polynomial in $x^p$ ??

Comment: I think that is precisely the first item that the exercise you posted asks for. Are you asking for more details for how to show the first lemma, or why we have to prove the lemma?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help, since the statement you wrote makes sense I think, I think. Put another way, the only way an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ can fail to be separable if it is of the form $g(x)^p$ for some polynomial $g$. (The coefficients of $g$ are in some bigger field.) This is not immediately obvious the first time and helps you understand inseparable extensions a bit.

Comment: So, at the first question do we have to show that $f$ is inseparable??

Comment: It isn't true that an irreducible polynomial is inseparable, so $f$ is not necessarily inseparable. The whole point of the exercise is see how $f$ can fail to be separable.

Comment: Ok... But I haven't understood how we could show it...

Comment: In the previous comment, I meant "it isn't true that an irreducible polynomial is separable". Do you know why irreducible polynomials are in fact separable in the case where the characteristic is 0? Maybe looking that up first will help.

Comment: When $f$ is irreducible, then $$f \text{ is separable } \Leftrightarrow (f, f')=1$$ 

We have that $(f, f')=1 \text{ or } f$. It stands that $(f, f')=f$ if $f' \equiv 0$. But in a field with characteristic $0$ $f'$ cannot be zero, when $f \not\equiv 0$. 
$$$$ 
So, we have that any irreducible polynomial in $K$ with $char K=0$ is separable. Is this correct??

Comment: Exactly, now when the characteristic of $K$ is $p>0$, the only thing that can go wrong with the proof you gave in characteristic 0 is that $f'$ might be zero. When might $f'$ be zero?

Comment: $$f(x)=a_0+a_1 x +\dots a_n x^n \Rightarrow f'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+\dots + na_nx^{n-1}$$
$f'$ is zero if the coefficients $a_i$ are divisible by $p$ or equal to $0$, right??

Comment: There's one more thing that can happen. If $n$ is divisible by $p$, then $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$ is zero.

Comment: Not only for $n$, it stands for each $i=1, 2, \dots , n$, right??

Comment: Right, I should have chosen a different letter than $n$ to represent an arbitrary exponent. The point is, if $f'=0$, then $a_i$ can be nonzero only if $p$ divides $i$.

Comment: Ok... And how can we cnclude from that, that $f$ is a polynomial in $x^p$ ??

Comment: You have just proven $f=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$ has the property that $a_i=0$ for $p$ not dividing $i$. This says exactly that $f$ is a polynomial in $x^p$. This step should be easier to see than the previous steps we have done, are you sure you understood what has been done so far?

Comment: I don't understand why it stands that "$f$ has the property that $a_i=0$ for $p$ not dividing $i$", means exactly that $f$ is apolynomial in $x^p$... Could you explain it to me??

Comment: Suppose $f=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. If the only nonzero coefficients are in degree divisible by $p$, then $p$ divides $n$. So $n=mp$ for some $m$ and $f(x)=x^{mp}+a_{(m-1)p}x^{(m-1)p}+a_{(m-2)p}x^{(m-2)p}+\cdots+a_0$. Then, $f(x)=g(x^p)$, where $g(x)=x^{m}+a_{(m-1)p}x^{m-1}+a_{(m-2)p}x^{(m-2)}+\cdots+a_0$.

Comment: Could you explain to me further the sentence:  "If the only nonzero coefficients are in degree divisible by $p$, then $p$ divides $n$." ??

Comment: Here, I'm assuming $f$ is monic for simplicity of notation, so $a_n=1$.

Comment: Does the sentence "If the only nonzero coefficients are in degree divisible by $p$, then $p$ divides $n$" mean that all the coefficients are equal to $0$ except for $a_n=1$ ??

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, if $p=3$ and $f(x)=x^6+x^3+1$, $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: I understand!! But how could we formulate it?? Maybe as followed??
$$$$
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+ \dots +a_nx^n \Rightarrow f'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+ \dots +na_nx^{n-1}$$ 
So that we have $f'(x) \equiv 0$ one of the following has to be satisfied: 
1) if $p\nmid i\Rightarrow a_i=0$ $\\$ 
2) if $p\mid i\Rightarrow i=mp$
So, the polynomial can be written as followed: 
$$f(x)=a_0+a_px^p+a_{2p}x^{2p}+ \dots + a_{kp}x^{kp}=a_0+a_px^p+a_{2p}(x^p)^2+\dots +a_{kp}(x^p)^k=g(x^p)$$ where $$g(x)=a_0+a_px+a_{2p}x^2+\dots +a_{kp}x^k$$ Is this correct?? Or could I improve something?? How could we show that $f(x)=g(x^{p^e})$??

Comment: Yeah, that's right. To show $f(x)=g(x^{p^e})$, you repeat the process again for the $g$ you wrote above, if $g$ isn't separable.

Comment: Ok... Do we have just to say that we repeat the process again for $g$, if $g$ isn't separable, so after some steps we get $f(x)=h(e^{p^e})$, or do we have to show something??

Comment: I don't think there's more to show. The only purpose to writing out more details is to convince yourself.

Comment: Ok!! I see... 
$$$$ 
For the second question: 
We know that $f(x)=h(x^{p^e})$, where $h(x)$ a separable polynomial of $K[x]$. Let $$h(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots +a_nx^n$$ so $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x^{p^e}+\dots +a_nx^{np^e}=a_0'^{p}+a_1'^{p}(x^{p^{e-1}})^p+\dots +a_n'^{p}(x^{np^{e-1}})^p\\ =a_0'^{p}+(a_1'x^{p^{e-1}})^p+\dots +(a_n'x^{np^{e-1}})^p=(a_0'+a_1'x^{p^{e-1}}+\dots +a_n'x^{np^{e-1}}))^p=\dots = (b_0^{p}+(b_1x)^p+\dots +(b_nx)^p)^{p^{e-1}}=((b_0+b_1x+\dots +b_nx)^p)^{p^{e-1}}=(b_0+b_1x+\dots +b_nx^n)^{p^{e}}=t(x)^{p^e}$$ where $t(x)=b_0+b_1x+\dots +b_nx^n$ 

Is this correct?? Could I improve something??

Comment: Yeah, I'm convinced you know how to do the second part from that.

Comment: Which do you mean is the second part??

Comment: I just mean the stuff after 2. in your original question

Comment: How could we show that $t(x)$, where $f(x)=(t(x))^{p^e}$ is in the closure $\overline{K}[x]$ ??

Comment: You just showed that the coefficients of $t$ are $p^{e}$th roots of the coefficients of $f$